# How to solve this error: Undefined reference to 'vtable for Enemy'?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Enemy{// step 1
public:
virtual void attack(); //now every enemy has the ability to attack. We know that every specific class (Ninja and monster have their own attack function).
 void setattackpower(int a){ attvar=a;};
protected:
    int attvar;
            };   //We have to use Virtual on order to avoid overwriting the function. Any class which inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.

class Ninja: public Enemy{ //step 2 code the function for each derived class
public:
    void attack(){
    cout << "ninja attack!-" << attvar<<endl;
    }
};
class Monster: public Enemy{
public:
    void attack(){
    cout << "Monster attack!-" <<attvar<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){// step 3
 Ninja n;
 Monster m;
 n.setattackpower(29);
 m.setattackpower(99);
Enemy *enemy1=&n;
Enemy *enemy2=&m;
enemy1->attack();
enemy2->attack();
};
```

Error: Undefined reference to 'vtable for Enemy'. 
I am using virtual function attack for the derived classes, while Enemy is the base class.

Comment: in `Enemy`, did you mean to do `virtual void attack() = 0;`?

Comment: You didn't define `virtual void attack();`. Either add `=0` to tell the compiler that you didn't indend to define it, or define it.

Answer (score 2):

`virtual void Enemy::attack();` requires implementation or should be "pure abstract":

```
class Enemy
{
    virtual void attack() = 0;
// ...
};
```

Comment: What is `::attack`?

Comment: @curiousguy: a typo.